# How to connect Nginx and PHP via Puppet (on Vagrant)?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, vagrant, puppet

I'm setting up a puppet file for Vagrant to use to provision a LEMP stack and so far, I've been able to install everything I need via this:

```
exec { "apt-get update":
command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update",
}

package { "acl":
    ensure => "present",
    require => Exec ["apt-get update"],
}

class nginx{
  package { "nginx":
    ensure => present,
    require => Exec ["apt-get update"],
  }
    service { "nginx":
        ensure  => "running",
        require => Package["nginx"],
    }

    file { "/var/www":
        ensure  => "link",
        target  => "/vagrant/web",
        require => Package["nginx"],
        notify  => Service["nginx"],
        force => true,
    }
}

class php {
    package { "php5-cli": ensure => present }
    package { "php5-dev": ensure => present }
    package { "php5-mysql": ensure => present }
    package { "php-pear": ensure => present }
    package { "php5-common": ensure => present}
    package { "php5-fpm": ensure => present}
    package { "php5-cgi": ensure => present}
    package { "php-apc": ensure => present}
    exec { "pear upgrade":
        command => "/usr/bin/pear upgrade",
require => Package["php-pear"],
    }
}
class mysql {
  package { "mysql-server":
    require => Exec["apt-get update"],
    ensure => present,
  }
  service { "mysql":
    enable => true,
    ensure => running,
    require => Package["mysql-server"],
  }
  exec { "Set MySQL server root password":
        require => Package["mysql-server"],
        unless => "/usr/bin/mysqladmin -uroot -proot status",
        command => "/usr/bin/mysqladmin -uroot password root",
  }
}  

include nginx
include php
include mysql
```

I've Vagrant setup correctly, I was using a LAMP stack script for that and it worked flawlessly; however, substituting Nginx for Apache and php-fpm for php5 caused a break. Whenever I try to load up my site, I get a "Welcome to nginx!". If I specify a specific path to an image (or any other static file), the image loads up. If I specify a specific path to a PHP file, the PHP file gets downloaded instead of executing.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

I'm thinking that the socket is not correctly setup from the Nginx side but I'm not entirely sure how I can set it up via a puppet manifests file for portability.

Ideas?

Comment: You are most probably missing nginx configuration for php5-fpm

Comment: @AurimasLičkus any idea on how to specify that via Puppet?

Answer (score 1):

You need puppet to replace the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file with a config that has the php socket stuff uncommented.

Try uncommenting the `location ~ \.php$` block and restart nginx to see if things work... if so then getting puppet to replace that file with your config should get it working for you.

There are quite a few more robust [nginx puppet scripts](https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx) out there that you might want to take a look at as well... you should probably being doing this as a vhost for example... and beware that there are some [security issues](http://docs.ngx.cc/en/latest/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls.html#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php) to look out for if using this in production.